# How to Change Domains in Payara Server for NetBeans Servlet Projects (Using Asadmin Cmd)

Tags: servlets, netbeans, payara

I'm currently working on two different servlet projects in Apache NetBeans. The first project I built from "New Projects" and was able to set up a Payara servlet with domain1. It works fine.

My issue shows up when I try and open a second project, built by someone else, that also uses servlets. When setting up the Payara servlet, it prompts me to create a new domain.

I was told the servlet I've already created should be listed on this page when "resolving missing server problem", but it's not.
[Missing Server From List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejk4F.png)

The pages that come after I try to resolve problem.
["domain1 is already registered"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18i5g.png)

[Need to use asadmin in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bytuO.png)

When I try to change domain name, it tells me to use a command terminal

```
asadmin> start-domain [domain name].
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to run asadmin in cmd. It does not recognize the command and seems to expect a batch file or something to run. I have tried running it in cmd Run As Admin as well. Still doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with others in the same course as me. It turns out the reason I was unable to open the second project was because it was expecting a very specific version of Java (1.8) and Payara Server (5.2022.2). Once I rebuilt my Payara Server with these version builds, I was able to use the same domain amongst all projects.